# Metric transforms that preserve $\ell^1$ embeddability

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, harmonic-analysis, kernels

Consider a function $f$ from reals to reals such that $f$, when applied to pairwise Manhattan distances between $n$ points, always results in a set of Manhattan distances.

Work by Schoenberg and Assouad show that any Bernstein function has this property (see Theorem 9.0.3 in the book *“Geometry of cuts and metrics”*, by Deza and Laurent). Recently, some collaborators and I showed that only Bernstein functions have this property. We published this [on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.11503) just now.

My question is: was this known before?

Comment: I was aware of the analogous result, when $\ell^1$-functions are replaced with conditionally negative definite functions. I'm not sure of a reference, possibly the book by Berg and Forst.